# search folder through directory ASP VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, directory

Is there a way to search folder name(whether its root folder or subfolder and with files inside) through web vb.net? I searched all over the internet and haven't found single help. this is what i've done so far. but this is in windows forms.
I am looking for web forms. thank you

```
 Protected Sub search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
        Dim MainFldr = "d:\shared\"
        Dim SKfiles() As System.IO.FileInfo
        Dim FldrInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(MainFldr)
        Dim flpth As String
        flpth = ""
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        SKfiles = FldrInfo.GetFiles("*" & txtfolder.Text & "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        For Each MySearchfile In SKfiles
            flpth = ""
            flpth = MySearchfile.DirectoryName + "\" + MySearchfile.Name
            ListBox2.Items.Add(flpth)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by creating search like below. searching folder name and subfolder.

```
 Dim files As FileInfo() = Nothing
 Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(startFolder)
 Dim dir As DirectoryInfo() = Nothing
 dir = dirInfo.GetDirectories(folderName, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        For i = 0 To dir.Length - 1

            If dir(i).Name = folderName Then
                Dim path2 = Directory.GetDirectories(dir(i).FullName)
                If path2.Length = 0 Then
                    files = dir(i).GetFiles()
                    For Each file In dir(i).GetFiles()
                        path = CStr(dir(0).FullName)
                        path = path.Remove(0, 11)
                        HiddenField1.Value = path & "\" & file.Name
                        HiddenField2.Value = file.Name
                        Dim tr As New TableRow
                        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = file.Name})
                        grd.Rows.Add(tr)
                        Dim tdlnk As New TableCell
                        Dim lnk As New HtmlAnchor
                        tdlnk.Controls.Add(lnk)
                        tr.Cells.Add(tdlnk)
                    Next
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Dim aaa As String = path2(0).Substring(path2(0).Length - 10)
                    startFolder = path2(0).ToString
                    folderName = aaa
                    Dim files1 As FileInfo() = Nothing
                    Dim dirInfo1 As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(startFolder)
                    Dim dir1 As DirectoryInfo() = Nothing
                    dirInfo1.GetDirectories(folderName, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    files1 = dirInfo1.GetFiles
                    For Each file In dirInfo1.GetFiles
                        path = CStr(dirInfo1.FullName)
                        path = path.Remove(0, 11)
                        HiddenField1.Value = path & "\" & file.Name
                        HiddenField2.Value = file.Name
                        Dim tr As New TableRow
                        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = file.Name})
                        grd.Rows.Add(tr)
                        Dim tdlnk As New TableCell
                        Dim lnk As New HtmlAnchor
                        tdlnk.Controls.Add(lnk)
                        tr.Cells.Add(tdlnk)
                    Next
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out you can do the same in web land.

However, one huge "issue" to remember?

For any web page url, web page link, web page document reference? You will use the web site URL for that file in question.

So, say you have the web site (root) and then a folder called Images.

images\cat.jpg

So, the path name for the WEB SITE MARK up will be:
"~/images/cat.jpg

however, WHEN you run code behind? (your vb.net code). Now, ALL AND EVERY file reference MUST be a full normal standard windows path name!!!

so, if say your vb.net code was to "test" if the above file existed?

Lets say we drop a button and a image control on a web page - we have this:

[image]

and lets just make this super simple - we want in vb code to set the above image control to a picture we have in our Content folder.

Well, you have to translate the web based url into a plane jane good old fashioned windows file path name!

So, you would do this:

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim strF As String
    strF = "~/Content/uncheck1.jpg"

    Dim strFInternal = Server.MapPath(strF)
    Debug.Print(strFInternal)
    If File.Exists(strFInternal) Then

        Image1.ImageUrl = strF

    End If


End Sub
```

Note how our INTERNAL code MUST use a good old plane jane windows file path name.

but for things on the web page? They are ALWAYS referenced from the point of view of the web site. After I run the above code I get this:

[image]

But that debug.print of the file name? This is the output:

```
Output:
C:\Users\AlbertKallal\source\repos\WebFriendlyTest\Content\uncheck1.jpg
```

Note VERY careful the above? It was a plane jane INTERNAL file name. I can't tell you how many times I struggled with above simple concept:

Web page controls and markup: use correct URL path names

Code behind: use full windows path name!!!

So, your posted code? it WILL work near as it stands!!!!

The only issue here is what folder you looking to push out to that list box?

Say in above, I wanted to push out ALL files in that Content Folder.

I mean, I can type in this to display that check box if I wanted to:

[image]

So the web page now displays that one simple image on the page - since I typed in the FULL correct url!!!

So, how about we drop a list box on the web form, and when we click our button, we display ALL files in that Content folder. Now I could "guess" the location of the file folder, but for ANY WEB page to use that folder, it HAS to be part of the web site folders (or sub folders). The web site can NOT just out of the blue map to steal or grab ANY file on the computer - those URL's can ONLY point to say root of the site + any sub folder.

So that content folder on this site is this:

[image]

So, as you can see, then I can type in a url that is the base site, and then that folder, and then that picture (uncheck1.jpg) that exists in that folder.

So, lets drop in a listbox, and push out all the files from that folder to the listbox on the form:

Our markup will be this:

[image]

So, just a button, and a list box.

And the button code for the Content folder? Well, we would use this:

(I removed the search part - but that is standard code - JUST like you ALWAYS used in the past!!!

So:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim MainFldr = "~/Content"
    Dim FldrInternal = Server.MapPath(MainFldr)

    Dim SKfiles() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim FldrInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FldrInternal)

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    SKfiles = FldrInfo.GetFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each MyFile In SKfiles

        ListBox1.Items.Add(MyFile.Name)

    Next


End Sub
```

I decided to NOT use the full path name - but I could have.

The output:

[image]

so just remember, that any web page? It can ONLY use files and things that are PART of the web site. And any url - even for a picture, file etc.? Then it MUST be a valid URL.

However, the code behind? It is NOT limited to JUST the folders and files from the root and sub folders. You can actually use your d: drive, or anything else that box on the network can get/grab/use/fetch. So the code behind is your plane jane windows code.

The web site URL and files from web pages thus can only use folders/files that are part of the web site. However, in some cases, say you had some other big server with folders for pictures and files - but your web site (and valid URL's) need to use that folder? Well, you then setup what is a called a virtual directory. This you quite much need to use IIS as opposed to using IIS express edition. (you can google for express edition + setup virutal folders).

Once that virtual folder is setup? It will look like any other sub folder in teh site - but they are not in the site anymore. (and this is also used for documents or PDF folders often too).

This is simply LOOKS like a sub folder, but it really is a folder that can point to any other folder on your computer network. of course this would only work if the final web server and published site location is running on a box on your server, and say not some hosting plan.

So one should code and NOT think in terms of full valid local server file names, but try to always think in terms of the URL, and the path name, and even path names in sub folders in that web site. But in all cases, the code behind operations are against plane jane valid full path names.

However, if you thought that debug.print of the simply .jpg file name was long or funny? Well, on a published server those file path names can be super crazy paths - but you NEVER care if you reference the folders as per above.